# How to make a single request with oauth delegated access to resources of multiple owners?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have an api that accesses personal files. I have persons that own a personal file and I have a consultant that can obtain access to view a personal file through oauth delegated access tokens. A person can revoke access to his personal file by revoking the access token. This works fine if the consultant wants to access a single personal file. But how do I make a request where the consultant can retrieve all files he has access tokens for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that the client makes uses a Client Credentials grant to the Authorization Server with a `scope` that indicates that it wants to get an access token for all currently granted access tokens. The Authorization Server would then consult its database of access tokens granted to the client and issues an access token that represents the combined set of current permissions.

Of course that would requires work on the Client, the Authorization Server and the Resource Server (API) side. There's no "out-of-the-box" solution for it that wouldn't require additional work.